# How to combine play framework and angular2?

Tags: angularjs, playframework, typescript, sbt, devops

My question is about how to organize the front and the back together in the project.
As far as I know, there are two ways to do such thing

1. Group the front and the back in one project using web-jars dependencies and sbt plugins. So sbt will run all the necessary operations like `uglify`, `concat`, `compilation` (`typescript` to `javascript`)...
2. Separate the front and the back and deploy them separately. In this case the back end  must add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This way the front and the back can be deployed in 2 different hosts. And the tool to be uses will be npm and gulp/grunt
3. Mix of 1 and 2. Still use the same repository for the front and the back but the front is build and generated by external tools like npm, bower and gulp/grunt

For the moment, there is not a lot of docs for option 2 and 3. Also the `typescript` plugin is not yet ready.

Which way is better for scala play + angular2 development ?

Comment: My winner is no. 1 - that way you minify requirement for specialist from other frameworks, even if you want to work in multi-domain stack and/or separate apps, you can use some solutions like some light HTTP server for reverse proxying/multidomains/load balancing... Your question is opinion based, so my answer may be only opinion as well :)

Comment: Thanks, but do you know some tutorial to do that with angular 2 and typescript. I saw some project on github but seems immature at this time

Comment: As @biesior mentioned, it's opinionated, I for one, don't like to split it up into 2 apps, I hate grunt/gulp configuration for the proxy settings. Play handles all that jazz, there is also the advantage that you don't have to configure any CORS settings. What I also did: I don't use webjars but bower/npm, they are located in the /public folder. I define an entry point for angular, for example: '/welcome' from there on angular takes the routing.  You might want to look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085544/play-framework-2-1-angularjs-routing-best-solution)

Comment: @biesior: Do you have any example that combine scala playframework and angular2 with typescript. I've got one example here https://github.com/lashford/modern-web-template#master but it's coffeescript!

Comment: see https://github.com/sbahmani/Play-Angul2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have been working with several Angular and Angular 2 apps recently and dealt with a similar problem. For all the scenarios, our backend and frontend apps were separate in terms of code and were communicating only via REST interfaces. Still, we deliver both - frontend and backend part and it felt natural to use one hosting server for both (could be Play Framework or Tomcat).

**Option #1**
At the beginning, we opted for this one. Webjars look like a miracle and several `sbt` or `maven` plugins can help you out with the minification, compilation, linting etc. of your frontend project. *This might go well for some.* Unfortunately, I have found this workflow unnatural. Some plugins were missing or their configuration was difficult. Webjars are not always up to date, some of them are automatically available, some not... etc. In a simple project it might work, but for me, it was not enough.

**Option #2**
We have tried separate servers for development but we quit fast. For most actions, you still need your both - frontend and backend server. So you have to start both. It means you have 2x more commands or workflows to remember and teach others. The CORS is not a big issue, but you might consider disabling it for production, that means extra work in the project. Developing backend or frontend separately was faster this way, but in my opinion, if you are to supply both - your development process should help you with it.

**Option #3**
That is the one we are using. With sbt it is possible and convenient. `SbtWeb` plugin allows you to set `playRunHooks` to whatever actions you would like to run with your project. The idea is to run a JavaScript build tool which will do all the necessary, frontend jobs, fe:

```
playRunHooks += {
  Process(Seq("npm", "install"), file(portal)).lines.foreach(println)
  RunSubProcess(portal, "npm", "run", "watch")
}
```

RunSubProcess can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hakobe/9925774).

So cutting the long story short, you let Play Server to serve your static content, but ignore its changes. This is taken care of by `npm`, `gulp`, `webpack`, `grunt` - whatever you choose. There is plenty of JavaScript build tools, plugins and templates to help you out. You do not need any `sbt` plugins, simply allow the JavaScript world to do its job. It might be difficult to set up at first but pays off quickly.

As a sample project you might want to check out Activator template [Play Framework with Angular 2 and Webpack 2](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-ng2-webpack2) and it's project is hosted on GitHub: [play-ng2-webpack2](https://github.com/lbialy/play-ng2-webpack2). It helped me out a bit.

It is also now possible using Tomcat, with [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) and developmentMode. The philosophy is similar.

Hope you find your way :).

Comment: any plans to release option #3 as a sbt plugin?